# Birefringent properties in Mylar films

Tags: optics, refraction, birefringence

Does Mylar film has birefringence properties? I am unsure about this and would like to know the reason behind its properties.

Comment: Likely, yes, given how it is made.

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between how it is made and the birefringence properties? Is it because the film is drawn biaxially?

Comment: Like many materials systems, the processing to get large sheets tends to align (crystal grains, polymer chains) along the rolling direction. This induces a (perhaps slight) asymmetry in mechanical,  optical, ... properties.

Comment: Easy enough to test with two crossed polarizers.

Comment: One of the first results from a Google search on 'mylar birefringence' states "Mylar is strongly birefringent, a serious inconvenience for measurements of polarized light."